# rails sunspot solr not working with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

rails sunspot solr not working with has_and_belongs_to_many

events -- has_and_belongs_to_many --tags

searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :description 
    text :tag_names do
     tags.map(&:name)
    end
  end

In the above example its working with title and description only. not with tag_names.

Answer (score 0):

well, i am assuming here that the tag_names is an array.. if that is the case, pls give it like this...

```
searchable do
  text :title, boost: 5 
  text :description
  text :tag_names, multiple: true do 
    tags.map(&:name)
  end 
end
```

(Try using the new hash notation... give `boost: 5` instead of `:boost => 5`.. This is just a suggestion.. your code will work irrespective of the mechanism that u follow..)